# How to "change" a record inside a list / array / enumerable?

Tags: c#, c#-record-type

I have a list of records that are immutable and I need to "change" a value in one of the records. It will of course mean creating a copy of the object with that value changed and then referencing the new records instead of the old one in the list.

I am wondering if there is some smart and neat way of doing it in C#. So far I have thought only of a straightforward way:

1. Get a copy of the record with changed value
2. Find the index of the record in the list
3. Assign the new reference

E.g:

```
var newRecord = oldRecord with { Field = newValue};
var index = list.IndexOf(oldRecord);
list[index] = newRecord;
```

Alternatively removing an item and putting a new one if it's not a list but an Enumerable e.g.

Comment: You can use clone() method to create copy and then change value in the cloned copy.  Some clone methods make a copy and others just the structure of the object.  Like cloning a datatable only creates a copy of the structure while a clone of a list object will make a duplicate of the data.

Comment: You could use indirection (e.g. `List<Pointer<Record>>`) or wrap your steps in an extension method. How you find / get `oldRecord`?

Comment: I do use some business logic with `FirstOrDefault()` based on field values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `dotnet` actually has a number of classes for these that are inside `System.Collections.Immutable`.

`ImmutableList` has a `Replace` function that will do exactly what I need.

It will return a new list as well, since it's the list itself that is immutable, so if that is not desired one must just implement an extension method that does about the same.

Comment: Note the code for `ImmutableList<T>.Replace` does the same as the code you show (i.e. `IndexOf` followed by `SetItem` (e.g. assignment)), but it does not change the existing `List` since (like records) it is an immutable collection, it creates a new collection with a changed item. I don't think that is what you need.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the details, I have figured out that much as well. So really I should just implement my own extension method to that :)